# How to get Drive Letter and Name

Tags: winapi

I want to get Drive Letter and Name. 
I used "DeviceIoControl" and "IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX" for this reason. I am using Microsoft Visual C++ ultimate Edition.

```
#define wszDrive L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0"

BOOL GetDriveParition(LPWSTR wszPath, DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX *pdg)
{
  HANDLE hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;  // handle to the drive to be examined 
  BOOL bResult   = FALSE;                 // results flag
  DWORD junk     = 0;                     // discard results

  hDevice = CreateFileW(wszPath,          // drive to open
                        0,                // no access to the drive
                        FILE_SHARE_READ | // share mode
                        FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
                        NULL,             // default security attributes
                        OPEN_EXISTING,    // disposition
                        0,                // file attributes
                        NULL);            // do not copy file attributes

  if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)    // cannot open the drive
  {
    return (FALSE);
  }


  bResult = DeviceIoControl(hDevice,                       // device to be queried
                            IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX, // operation to perform
                            NULL,
                            0,                       // no input buffer
                            pdg,
                            sizeof(*pdg),            // output buffer
                            &junk,                         // # bytes returned
                            NULL);          // synchronous I/O

  CloseHandle(hDevice);

  return (bResult);
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{

  DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX pdg; // disk drive partition structure
  BOOL bResult = FALSE;      // generic results flag

  bResult = GetDriveParition (wszDrive, &pdg);


  if (bResult) 
  {
    wprintf(L"Drive path            = %ws\n",   wszDrive);
    wprintf(L"Partition Style       = %I64d\n", pdg.PartitionStyle);
    wprintf(L"Partition Count       = %ld\n",   pdg.PartitionCount);
  } 
  else 
  {
    wprintf (L"GetDrivePartition  failed. Error %ld.\n", GetLastError ());
  }

  getch();
}
```

but when I was performing I confronted to an error which was "error 122".

Comment: Something tells me you should learn C++ basics _before_ spending thousands of dollars on a C++ IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you meant to say error code 122 rather than 22. That error is `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`. As [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365174.aspx), you will need to allocate a larger buffer and try again.

The point here is that the struct is a variable sized struct. You need to allocate dynamic memory large enough to hold information for all the partitions.

Something like this should get you going in the right direction:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define wszDrive L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0"

BOOL GetDriveParition(LPWSTR wszPath, DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX *pdg, size_t size)
{
  HANDLE hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;  // handle to the drive to be examined 
  BOOL bResult   = FALSE;                 // results flag
  DWORD junk     = 0;                     // discard results

  hDevice = CreateFileW(wszPath,          // drive to open
                        0,                // no access to the drive
                        FILE_SHARE_READ | // share mode
                        FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
                        NULL,             // default security attributes
                        OPEN_EXISTING,    // disposition
                        0,                // file attributes
                        NULL);            // do not copy file attributes

  if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)    // cannot open the drive
  {
    return (FALSE);
  }


  bResult = DeviceIoControl(hDevice,                       // device to be queried
                            IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX, // operation to perform
                            NULL,
                            0,                       // no input buffer
                            pdg,
                            size,            // output buffer
                            &junk,                         // # bytes returned
                            NULL);          // synchronous I/O

  CloseHandle(hDevice);

  return (bResult);
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{

  DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX* pdg; // disk drive partition structure
  BOOL bResult = FALSE;      // generic results flag

  size_t size = sizeof(DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX) + 10*sizeof(PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX);
  pdg = (DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX*) malloc(size);
  bResult = GetDriveParition (wszDrive, pdg, size);

  if (bResult) 
  {
    wprintf(L"Drive path            = %ws\n",   wszDrive);
    wprintf(L"Partition Style       = %I64d\n", pdg->PartitionStyle);
    wprintf(L"Partition Count       = %ld\n",   pdg->PartitionCount);
  } 
  else 
  {
    wprintf (L"GetDrivePartition  failed. Error %ld.\n", GetLastError ());
  }

  free(pdg);
}
```

I've cast the return value of `malloc` since you state that you are using a C++ compiler.

Comment: I did it and I have this error : "cannot convert from 'void *' to 'DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX *  " for line : pdg = malloc(size);

Comment: Ok, you are using C++. My code is C. Compile my code as C and it will compile. Or cast the return value of malloc.